# can't get page border to sit over content

Tags: css

I have a website that requires a border round the edge. This has been implemented with divs of block colour that are placed around the edges of the screen. This works for most of the site, but one one section, the content overlaps the borders (see here, and scroll down: http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/#range).

I've tried putting the z-index of the range items (a.item) to -1, and this then sits below the border but it makes the links not clickable. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the border divs from `<header>` tag to just before the closing `</body>` tag, and then adding `z-index:11;` to `.border-divs` (line 1094) fixes the issue for me

using the latest version of Chrome. (30.0.1599.69 m)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `z-index:11;` to `#bottom-pink` and `#top-pink`.

Comment: That has no effect I'm afraid.

Comment: It is working for me on Mozilla, Chrome and IE for z-index:11;

Comment: I'm on chrome on ubuntu 12.04 and it's not working for me. Looks like I might be the odd one out here...

Answer (score 0):

Your images have a z-index of 10, there for your borders need to have a higher z-index to to be on the top of them.  This is why the rest of the text is not showing through and only the images are.

The position attribute of the borders also needs to be absolute or relative not fixed in order for chrome to respect the z-index attribute.

[image]

Comment: I've tried changing the z-indexes. The problem is that when the z-index of the link is lower than that of the border, the link becomes unclickable, even when it is not below the border.

Comment: Check the picture I just added.  I just checked it and I can still click on the image and it is not showing above the border

Comment: That's really odd - I've just tried that (chrome) and it doesn't work (see image: http://i.imgur.com/2RLPJxX.png). Although I've just tried your solution in firefox and it works.

Comment: Z-index only works on position:absolute or position: relative in chrome.  I did not notice it was set to fixed